# Transforming two columns with text to dummy variables with each word of the text representing a new column

Tags: r, variables, text

For my master thesis I am analyzing courses at a university. I have 1141 courses (as rows) with 4 variables (as columns). A preview of the dataset is provided below:

[Preview dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XznEj.png)

The dataset can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13L2qBGJ872RyrxHrol_zQK3DjNjD5KeC/view?usp=sharing).

In the columns Description and LearningOutcomes there is filtered (without stopwords, punctuation etc) text. Each word of this text I would like to transform in a dummy variable. There's a total of 10.493 independent words. An example would be for one instance:

[Intended output as Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItjjN.png)

So far I have been struggling with the Tidyr separate function, however I am not getting output from it. Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

PS the dataset to be transformed is on the last line named "database2"

```
rm(list=ls());

#import database                       
database <- read_excel("/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/TU e Innovation Management /Thesis/testdatabasematrix.xlsx");

#name columns
colnames(database)[1] <- "Name";
colnames(database)[2] <- "Description";
colnames(database)[3] <- "LearningOutcomes";


# import packages
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

# here the text transformations for titles
title <- tibble(line = 1:nrow(database), text = database$Name) %>%        # as tibble
  unnest_tokens(word, text)%>%                                     # remove punctuations, lowercase, put words in column
  anti_join(stop_words, by = c("word" = "word")) %>%               # remove stopwords
  group_by(line) %>% summarise(title = paste(word,collapse =' '))  # now all in a row!

# here the text transformations for descriptions
description <- tibble(line = 1:nrow(database), text = database$Description) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%  
  anti_join(stop_words, by = c("word" = "word"))  %>%
  group_by(line) %>% summarise(title = paste(word,collapse =' '))

# here the text transformations for learning outcomes
learningoutcomes <- tibble(line = 1:nrow(database), text = database$LearningOutcomes) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words, by = c("word" = "word"))  %>%
  group_by(line) %>% summarise(title = paste(word,collapse =' '))

# now the full dataset
database2 <- title %>% left_join(description, by = 'line') %>% left_join(learningoutcomes, by = 'line')
colnames(database2) <- c("line","Name","Description","LearningOutcomes")
database2

# to do: stemming and remove numbers

#wordfreq_LearningOutcome <- data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(tolower(database2$LearningOutcomes), " "))))
#wordfreq_Description <- data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(tolower(database2$Description), " "))))
```

Code for AEF:

```
testdata <- database2

transformed_data <- 
  testdata %>% 

  ## split the strings into a list of words
  mutate_at(vars(Description, LearningOutcomes), funs(strsplit(., " "))) %>% 

  ## in each row, concatenate the lists from description and outcomes
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(words_used = list(unique(c(Description, LearningOutcomes)))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 

  ## the old variables are no longer needed
  select(-Description, -LearningOutcomes) %>% 

  ## unnest the data to get a row for each course/word combination
  unnest(words_used) %>% 

  ## add a dummy variable that indicates that all combinations in the data are indeed present
  mutate(present = 1) %>% 

  ## use spread to convert from tall to wide format. Use 0 as filling for missing combinations
  spread(words_used, present, fill=0)

transformed_data
```

Comment: Hi, generally it's not a good practice to give links to download, I'm sure you have the best intentions, but anyone can't say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created some test data because your link was not accessible:

```
library(tidyverse)

testdata <-
  tribble(~coursename, ~description, ~outcomes,
          "Course1", "word1 word2 word3", "word7 word4 word5",
          "Course2", "word3 word4", "word6 word1 word7",
          "Course3", "word3 word1 word8 word9", "word2")

> testdata
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  coursename description             outcomes         
  <chr>      <chr>                   <chr>            
1 Course1    word1 word2 word3       word7 word4 word5
2 Course2    word3 word4             word6 word1 word7
3 Course3    word3 word1 word8 word9 word2
```

You can transform the data with dplyr in multiple steps:

```
transformed_data <- 
  testdata %>% 

  ## split the strings into a list of words
  mutate_at(vars(description, outcomes), funs(strsplit(., " "))) %>% 

  ## in each row, concatenate the lists from description and outcomes
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(words_used = list(unique(c(description, outcomes)))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 

  ## the old variables are no longer needed
  select(-description, -outcomes) %>% 

  ## unnest the data to get a row for each course/word combination
  unnest(words_used) %>% 

  ## add a dummy variable that indicates that all combinations in the data are indeed present
  mutate(present = 1) %>% 

  ## use spread to convert from tall to wide format. Use 0 as filling for missing combinations
  spread(words_used, present, fill=0)
```

This gives:

```
> transformed_data
# A tibble: 3 x 10
  coursename word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Course1        1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     0
2 Course2        1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
3 Course3        1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1
```

Comment: Dear AEF, thanks for your comment!

I have implemented your code and that works perfectly. However, when I try to adjust it for my orignal database I get the error of: "## use spread to convert from tall to wide format. Use 0 as filling for missing combinations
+   spread(words_used, present, fill=0)
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "quosures""

I have edited my earlier post with the code used in the end. What am I missing? Thanks! Best, Christiaan

Comment: There seem to be two errors with your code: 1) There is no "beginning" of the chain. My chain begins with the line 'testdata %>%' while yours begins directly with 'mutate_at(...)'. Probably you forgot the '%>%' symbol in the first line. 2) Use the column names directly, e.g. 'Description' instead of 'transformed_data$Description'. That should do the trick.

Comment: Dear AEF. When I restarted my R software, suddenly the code that I had written didn't work anymore. The fault it mentions is: " +   ## use spread to convert from tall to wide format. Use 0 as filling for missing combinations
+   spread(words_used, present, fill=0)
Error in select(., -Description, -LearningOutcomes) : 
  unused arguments (-Description, -LearningOutcomes)
>   
> transformed_data
Error: object 'transformed_data' not found". I have tried reinstalling the packages, rewriting the code but again I seem to miss it. Code is updated in post above. Sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: It seems to be correct. Without access to the data I cannot test it. I would check 1) if the variable 'database2' still contains the expected content (otherwise the error would be in your code that creates 'database2') 2) execute the pipe step by step: The first line, the first two lines, the first three lines and so on. Test in which line the error first occurs.